# For a given CDF compute $\Bbb P(X^2 \in A)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let
$$
F(x)=\begin{cases}
0  &  \text{if} & x <-1\\
\frac{1}{4} & \text{if} & x \in [-1,0)\\
\frac{x+1}{4} & \text{if} & x \in [0,3)\\
1 & \text{if} & x >3
\end{cases}
$$

I need to get $\Bbb P(X^2 \in (\frac{1}{9},1]) $ and I got
\begin{align}
\Bbb P(X^2 \in (\frac{1}{9},1]) &= \Bbb P(X\in [-1,-\frac{1}{3})\cup(\frac{1}{3},1]) \\
&= F(1)-F(\frac{1}{3})+F(-1)-F(-\frac{1}{3})=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4} \\
&=\frac{1}{5}
\end{align}
Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $F(1)-F(\frac{1}{3})+F(-\frac{1}{3})-F(-1)$, not $F(1)-F(\frac{1}{3})+F(-1)-F(-\frac{1}{3})$,

though in this particular case they happen to be te same.

Finally, $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{6}$, not $\frac{1}{5}$.